# Override EditorTemplate based on BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I am using EditorTemplates to style all my input fields. Works like a charm, however now I want two themes of EditorTemplates, one for normal forms, and then one for my wizard forms.

I am already using an overloaded Html.BeginWizardForm() around those Html.EditorFor - but how do I make the MVC logic react on being inside Html.BeginWizardForm() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is as stated by Chris Pratt not possible to have multiple EditorTemplates.

I however found a workaround by extending the MvcForm and created a WizardForm which adds a value to the ViewContext (in my case "wizardContext" => true) and on disposing setting wizardContext => false.

This allows me in the EditorTemplates to add a check for if I am inside or outside the wizardContext, which will propagate through the nested EditorFor, and in this way allow me to have different themes, without having to be specific in EditorFor.

Answer (score 0):

EditorTemplates are designed to be somewhat global. You can override them, though, just like any other view, because they are just views. For example, assuming you have something like `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml`, you can then create a another view at `Views\Foo\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml`, and for any action called from `FooController`, the latter editor template will be used instead of the one from `Shared`. You might be able to make this work in your scenario if the wizard form is used in a specific controller or area context.

Short of that, though, there's no way to have this occur automatically. Some manual options still exist, though.

1. You can decorate the properties of the view model used within the context of the wizard with `UIHint` attributes. For example, assuming the same shared editor template above, you could do something like:

   ```
   [UIHint("WizardString")]
   public string Foo { get; set; }
   ```

   That would cause it to look for `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\WizardString.cshtml` instead.
2. You can pass the editor template to use in the call to `EditorFor`:

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo, "WizardString")
   ```

All that said, the biggest problem here is that you seem to be violating a pretty core principal of good web design. HTML is about structure, not presentation. CSS is for presentation. As a result, if you want something to look different in a certain context, the correct approach is to apply different CSS. If things are designed well, your HTML shouldn't really have to change.

Comment: I am in no way violating core principals - In my case I'm using both bootstrap inline and horizontal forms based on the type of form. Here themes of editor templates would fit perfectly as the html markup changes.

Comment: Editor templates shouldn't include your actual form element, and that is where you alternatively apply either the `form-horizontal` or `form-inline` class. All the markup for the actual fields is the same in either case. So, yes, if you're actually including your form element in the editor template, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Please explaing how <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div> and 
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div> is the same markup?